# Array as member of the class does not take input from cin

Tags: c++, arrays, class, cin

I am trying to define a class which takes an input from user and stores it in an array member of class 'Player'

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << "Enter scores: ";
        cin >> player1.score[i] >> player2.score[i] ;
        if (player1.score[i] > player2.score[i]) {
            if (player1.highscore < player1.score[i]){
                player1.highscore = player1.score[i] ;
                }
        }
```

Also here is the class definition

```
class Player
{
public:
    Player (int n) ;
    int highscore ;
    int score[] ;
};

Player::Player (int n) {
    int i ;
    cout << "Player created" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        score[i] = 0 ;
}
```

Upon running after the program asks for scores, it stops and outputs this number:
132767

Comment: You mean it prints `132767`?

Comment: Please, show initialization of `player1` and `player2`.

Comment: Yes, and program ended with exit code: 0 after that

Comment: Player player1(roundNum) ;
    Player player2(roundNum) ;

Comment: You seem to be `using namespace std;`. [Don't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no runtime sized arrays in C++, and `int score[]` does not magically give you an array of size `n`.

Use an [`std::vector<int> score;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. With that, your constructor will look like this:

```
Player::Player(int n) : score(n) {
    std::cout << "Player created\n";
}
```

`score` will be correctly initialized to `0` and have space for `n int`s.

Comment: But how do I declare it in the class definition?

Comment: @EduardKim Just replace the `int[]` line with the `std::vector` line and `#include <vector>`.